# Angular - Show component on row clicked

Tags: angular

I'm trying to show a little loading spinner next to the row clicked.

My current component looks something like this.

Main.component.html

```
 <mat-selection-list #months [multiple]="false" >
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let month of listOfMonths" (click)="selectedDate(month)">
        <mat-card class="my-1 px-1 py-2 sm-shadow">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <ng-container *ngIf="loading$ | async" >
              <loading-spinner
                class="loading-spinner"
                [active]="true"
                [diameter]="20"
                [strokeWidth]="2"
                [colour]="'primary'"
              ></loading-spinner>
            </ng-container>
            <fa-icon [icon]="cIcon" class="c-icon"></fa-icon>
            <div class="settlement-item flex-fill mx-2 d-flelx align-items-center justify-content-between">
              <span class="info" data-test="date">{{ month }}</span>
            </div>
            <fa-icon [icon]="icon" class="download-icon"></fa-icon>
          </div>
        </mat-card>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-selection-list>
```

When a row is clicked it will currently display the *'loading-spinner*' until the state has returned success / failure. The problem is this is showing on every row and I can't think of a way to only display it on the event clicked {{ month }}.

The loading spinner is a simple component of 'mat-progress-spinner'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I created a 'selectedMonth' value and set to be empty like:
`selectedMonth: string = '';`

Then within my click event 'selectedDate(month)' I changed the value of selctedMonth to be the value of month.

`this.selectedMonth = month;`

Within the HTML I just did a *ngif=selectedMonth === month" on the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use the *ngFor row index to select the specific row?

Something like:

```
 <mat-selection-list #months [multiple]="false" >
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let month of listOfMonths;let indexOfelement=index;" (click)="selectedDate(month)">
        <mat-card class="my-1 px-1 py-2 sm-shadow">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <ng-container *ngIf="showRow(indexOfelement)" >
              <loading-spinner
                class="loading-spinner"
                [active]="true"
                [diameter]="20"
                [strokeWidth]="2"
                [colour]="'primary'"
              ></loading-spinner>
            </ng-container>
            <fa-icon [icon]="cIcon" class="c-icon"></fa-icon>
            <div class="settlement-item flex-fill mx-2 d-flelx align-items-center justify-content-between">
              <span class="info" data-test="date">{{ month }}</span>
            </div>
            <fa-icon [icon]="icon" class="download-icon"></fa-icon>
          </div>
        </mat-card>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-selection-list>
```

And control de row indexOfelement in the row click.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a loading boolean attribute to your month interface.

```
<mat-selection-list #months [multiple]="false">
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let month of listOfMonths" (click)="selectedDate(month)">
        <mat-card class="my-1 px-1 py-2 sm-shadow">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <ng-container *ngIf="month.loading" >
              <loading-spinner
                class="loading-spinner"
                [active]="true"
                [diameter]="20"
                [strokeWidth]="2"
                [colour]="'primary'"
              ></loading-spinner>
            </ng-container>
            <fa-icon [icon]="cIcon" class="c-icon"></fa-icon>
            <div class="settlement-item flex-fill mx-2 d-flelx align-items-center justify-content-between">
              <span class="info" data-test="date">{{ month }}</span>
            </div>
            <fa-icon [icon]="icon" class="download-icon"></fa-icon>
          </div>
        </mat-card>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-selection-list>
```